# Is there a CSS attribute to apply for OSX Web Browsers, similar to IE9?

Tags: macos, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bit of a problem with my web development.

I work for a company that, in part, builds webpages for clients connecting to a local hotspot (i.e. the "Welcome to our WiFi" page). It's been recently brought to my attention that the User to a device using OSX is reporting the webpage misaligned, compared to Windows, Android, and iOS devices.

The basis of my question is: **Is there a CSS3 friendly chunk of code I can drop into the stylesheet specific to OSX browsers**, much like how Internet Explorer 9 CSS settings can be statically set by adding :root to the beginning of an element in CSS?

CSS example for IE9:

```
.header { margin-left:20px; } /* Examples of current browsers for laptops or desktops */
:root .header { margin-left:30px \0/IE9; } /* Example of Internet Explorer 9 code */
```

I did a quick check around, but couldn't find anything in particular answering my question. Any help is appreciated.

Also, as a point of interest, I realize there is the -webkit- property that can be applied to some element arguments that would affect Safari browsers, but I'm looking for something specific to OSX devices. Again, any help on the matter is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

~DanceLink

Comment: This is a bit OT, so I'am sorry. But users can use OSX and Firefox, which will render pretty much like the windows version. It should not be necessary to have hacks for such modern browsers for a simple task like alignment. Do you have a certain problem you could put in a demo?

Comment: When possible, you should avoid doing this, your base CSS should work and be tested in all your chosen supported browsers. A lot of the time, you can avoid browser discrepencies almost entirely by taking advantage of a CSS framework like Twitter.Bootstrap for handling your layout, as these frameworks are already tested for a multitude of browsers and mobile devices, why make it so hard on yourself?

Comment: Mitchell Lee: We actually use a (now deprecated) version of Bootstrap, but until now we've not heard of any alignment issues with other devices (i.e. OS X devices). Very minimal adjustments were made to the bootstrap code itself before being uploaded to our service page. While technically possible that it's something in the code that was modified that's causing the issue, it would be **highly unlikely** as the changes applied were mostly to font-size of 2 specific areas. Shouldn't affect alignment much to my understanding.

Comment: Nico O: To answer your question, I actually can't replicate the issue right now as I have no OS X device to demo with, or at least handy atm (EOD Friday). :(

Comment: As others have said, you are heading down the wrong path. A alignment issue like that points to buggy code, so it's better to get that fixed.

Comment: To add some context to my problem, has anyone here heard of "OS X Hotspot Assistant"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For issues such as this, I often rely on CSS Browser Selector: https://github.com/ridjohansen/css_browser_selector/  -- it does require adding a script.